# Why is this set not countably infinite, and overall rules concerning defining mappings

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

The set in question is all numbers of the form $\sin(n\frac{\pi}{2})$ where $n$ is an integer. Can't you define a mapping such that $0,1,0,-1$ gets mapped to real numbers. I.e. $0$ if $n$ is odd, $-1$ if $n \pmod 4 \equiv 0$, and $1$ otherwise?

$$\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & \ldots \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & \ldots \\
\end{matrix}$$

Little confused here. Thanks!

Comment: It's a set, not a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset): You don't count multiple appearances of the same number.  Therefore the set of all numbers of that form has only $\_\_\_$ elements (fill in the blank).

Comment: The mapping isn't 1-1 if the three values each get mapped to multiple values.  From 1,0,-1 to Z is not a function.  And from Z to 1,0-1 is not injective.

Answer (score 1):

The set in question is not infinite. $\sin(n\frac{\pi}{2})$ can only take the values $-1$, $0$ and $1$ for integers $n$.

The 'mapping' you propose is not a function. To be function a relation must be well-defined (i.e. the left hand elements must be associated to exactly one element). You have $0$, $1$ and $-1$ each associated to multiple elements.